# Apache RewriteRule get rid of leading /

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRule:

`RewriteRule ^/jenkins :8080 [P]`

When I go to the URL, I would like to be able to enter the IP `10.55.55.23/jenkins` and redirect to the login page of Jenkins. However, I have to enter the port number to actually get it to work:

`10.55.55.23:8080/jenkins`

How can I create a `RewriteRule` that ignores the need for a port number?

Answer (score 0):

This rule does the trick

```
RewriteRule ^/?jenkins$ http://10.55.55.23:8080/jenkins [P]
```

Anyway, I still can't figure out the title of your question. How does `get rid of leading slash` is related ?